# Play sound using javascript in safari

Tags: javascript, browser, audio, embed, playsound

I want to play sound onclick event. I have code in which i can play sound in Firefox and other browser but not in safari.
Below is the code. Safari gives me the error like `"thissound.Play" [undefined ] is not a function`.

```
function EvalSound(soundobj) {
  var thissound= eval("document."+soundobj);
  thissound.Play();
}

<embed src="namaste_london01(www.songs.pk).mp3" autostart=false width=0 height=0 name="sound1"
enablejavascript="true">

<a href="#" onClick="EvalSound('sound1')"> Play </a>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `eval`? You could simply use `document['sound1'].Play()`.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has some great audio plugins. It also means you can get rid of nasty onclick attributes, and so keep all your javascript between the script tags.

Comment: Your JavaScript should not be between `<script>` tags at all, actually. Be unobstrusive and keep it in files only.

Comment: @Elusive - depends - no point in making another connection to the server for 5 lines of script. However, there comes a point, when yes, putting it in a separate file is definitely the way to go :)